# Refreshing the UITableView only works when I move the table?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

I have a UITableView where a user clicks on an accessory.  The accessory launches a UIView in modal view (using `presentViewController`).

When it returns it is meant to update the tableview cell with the required data.

Currently I am using a Singleton to capture userData inside a dictionary; but even if I use a NSNotification I have the same issue.

> My issue is that when the modal dialog is dismissed the tableview never updates; however 
>   if I scroll or otherwise physically move then table the entry in the cell is updated.

I get the same results if I try to force reload a cell or the entire tableview with NSNotifications.

I am wondering if I can get some help on this; how do I make the cell reload?

The code relating to cell display and how the modal is presented is below;

Notes;

`_eventName is just a NSString`

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if ( [[MySingleton sharedInstance].userData objectForKey:@"eventName"] !=nil) {
        _eventName = [[MySingleton sharedInstance].userData objectForKey:@"eventName"];
    }
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    NSDictionary *dict;
    NSString *name;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    dict = [_template objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    name = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];

    cell.textLabel.text = name;

    NSString *key = [[dict objectForKey:@"key"] lowercaseString];

    if ([[key lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"name"]==YES) {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = _eventName;
    }



    return cell;
}



-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tv accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [_template objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *key = [[dict objectForKey:@"key"] lowercaseString];

    NSString *name = @"";

    if ([key isEqualToString:@"name"]==YES) {

        EventNameVC *nameEditor = [[EventNameVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"EventNameVC" bundle:nil];

        if (_eventName !=nil) {
            nameEditor.txtName.text = _eventName;
        } else {
            nameEditor.txtName.text = name;
        }

        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nameEditor];


// When we return from the view, reload the cell.
        [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:^{

            [self.tv reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

        }];

        nav = nil;
    }

}
```

---

Edit: Tried to use a notification to detect the modal's closure; but I still have the same issue -- that is, the UITableView only displays the updated data when I physically move the table.

In my view controller I do this;

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

        NSOperationQueue *mainQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];

        self.notificationObserver = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                                     addObserverForName:@"dismissModalView"
                                     object:nil
                                     queue:mainQueue
                                     usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification) {
                                        NSLog(@"Notification received!");

                                        NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
                                        _eventName = [userInfo objectForKey:@"eventName"];

                                        NSLog(@"received._eventName = %@", _eventName);

                                         [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateTable) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
                                    }];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void) updateTable {
NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
[self.tv reloadData];
}
```

I launch my modalView inside the `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` method

```
EventNameVC *nameEditor = [[EventNameVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"EventNameVC" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nameEditor];
        [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Okay, so when we launch the modal view using `presentViewController` and on dismissal, the notification is fired.

In my modal view

```
-(IBAction) btnSave:(id)sender {
    [self.txtName resignFirstResponder];

    ///[[MySingleton sharedInstance].userData setObject:self.txtName.text forKey:@"eventName"];
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.txtName.text forKey:@"eventName"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"dismissModalView" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When I run this, the updateTable is fired correctly and logged in the console.

So far so good.

But the tableview still has not refreshed its data; I still have to physically move the table to make the cell update.

What can I do to force the cells to update to correctly?

Comment: Try calling `reloadData` on your table view to force it to refresh.

Comment: When you say put the reloadData on tableView, in which method?  Do you mean in the completion block of `[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion...`  or elsewhere?

Comment: I have tried to put reloadData inside `viewWillAppear' like `[self.tv reloadData];` this does not cause the cell to display correctly.

Comment: Stupid question:  When reloadData is invoked, does `self.tv` point to the correct table view?

Comment: Yes it does.  But I will try to rewrite the entire view just in case I made a silly mistake

Comment: I think I did make a silly mistake in my code, so I rewrote it all and it all seems fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `– reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` when you present the view controller (nav). The 'completion' block gets executed when the OS is finished displaying the view controller (not when the view returns, as you put it) and thus is visible to the user.

Try calling `– reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` when you dismiss the view controller. That could go in the 'completion' block of `– dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE:**

Hi Cardigan; I've seen your updated question and let me tell you, if the `updateTable` method is getting called correctly after the dismissal of the `EventNameVC` controller it means the issue is somewhere else. Calling `reloadData` on your table view will cause it to refresh it's contents with whatever changes you made to the underlying data source, unless... the data source hasn't been updated by the time you call `reloadData`.

By looking at your `– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method I can see you get the information for your cells from these two lines of code:

```
dict = [_template objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
name = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
```

The information comes from the `_template` array. Now, in your modal view you have the `textName` property which I'm assuming is what you want to ultimately display in the table view, right? When the view controller is dismissed you send that information inside a dictionary using a notification but when you receive that notification I don't see anywhere in your block where you add that information to the `_template` array. How do you update your data source?

Please also try the following:

Add a breakpoint to the `updateTable` method. When the application stops at it add another breakpoint but this time to the `– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method; that will show you if the `reloadData` method is working correctly. If the application then stops in `– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` then you're in the right path. At that point proceed to view the contents of the data source. You can do this by typing `po _template` (then hit enter) directly to the XCode console. That way you'll be able to see if it's been updated with the information you want.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Okay, I will try this. I've been trying to figure out where I went wrong, so maybe this will help solve it

Comment: Hello there. I have tried to use a NSNotification to reload the entire table. It listens for a modal dismissal. The notification works; but the table still does not display correctly until I physically move the tableview.  You mention in your answer that I can use `reloadRows...` inside the `dismissViewControllerAnimated` but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: I've totally rewrote my uitableview got rid of all the junk and made it simple, for some reason it is now working. I am going to accept your answer because I'm not sure what I did to fix it.  But it is now updating my table properly.  I only have 3 rows in the table so reloading a whole tableview is not expensive in this case scenario.  I will post the code I used below.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted @LuisCein's answer.  I re-wrote my tableview.  It is now updating;

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization        
        self.pTemplate = [[MySingleton sharedInstance] pTemplate];

        NSOperationQueue *mainQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         addObserverForName:@"dismissModalView"
         object:nil
         queue:mainQueue
         usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification) {
             NSLog(@"Notification received!");

             NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
             _eventName = [userInfo objectForKey:@"eventName"];

             NSLog(@"received._eventName = %@", _eventName);

             [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
         }];

    }
    return self;
}

...

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tv numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return pTemplate.count;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    NSDictionary *dict = [self.pTemplate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *name = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];

    cell.textLabel.text = name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Detail text";

    NSString *key = [[dict objectForKey:@"key"] lowercaseString];

    if ([[key lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"name"]==YES) {

        if (_eventName !=nil) cell.detailTextLabel.text = _eventName;
    }

    if ([[key lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"date"]==YES) {
        NSString *dateString = [dateFormater stringFromDate:_eventDate];
        if (_eventDate !=nil) cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dateString];
    }

    if ([[key lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"venue"]==YES) {
        if (_venueName != nil) cell.detailTextLabel.text = _venueName;
    }

    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor  = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    return cell;
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tv accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [self.pTemplate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *key = [[dict objectForKey:@"key"] lowercaseString];

    if ([key isEqualToString:@"name"]==YES) {

        if (_eventName !=nil) {
            [[MySingleton sharedInstance].userData setObject:_eventName forKey:@"eventName"];
        }

        EventNameVC *nameEditor = [[EventNameVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"EventNameVC" bundle:nil];

        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nameEditor];
        [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];

        nav = nil;
    }

    if ([key isEqualToString:@"date"]==YES) {

    }

    if ([key isEqualToString:@"venue"]==YES) {

    }
}
```

This code is displaying my uitableview and cells correctly, I go to the view, make a change to the text and submit a nsnotification.

```
-(IBAction) btnSave:(id)sender {
    [self.txtName resignFirstResponder];

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.txtName.text forKey:@"eventName"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"dismissModalView" object:self userInfo:userInfo];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Everything seems to work now.  The uitableview is now updating without me having to scroll anything.

It might be just some silly mistake, but I am happy now it is resolved.

Thanks for all to helped!